# Broadcastreceiver or interface to communicate between 2 activities?

Tags: java, android, interface, broadcastreceiver

Should i use an interface or a broadcastreceiver to send data between 2 activities?

For communication between my fragment and activities i opted for an interface, but can i also use an interface between 2 activities?

Both do the same, but which one i preferred for activity to activity communication?

**Interface for my fragment-activity**

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SongsFragment.OnClickSong { 
... }

@Override
public void onClickSongTab1(int position, ArrayList<Song> songs) {
...
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public interface OnClickSong{
    void onClickSongTab1(int position, ArrayList<Song> songList);
}

@Override
public void onClickSong(int position, ArrayList<Song> songList) {

    onClickSongListener.onClickSongTab1(position, songList);

}
```

**EDIT**

I want to send data to an already running activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For activity to activity communication you can use Intent with extra bundles.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, <Activity destination class type>);
intent.putExtra("<key>",<value>);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Actually in Android 2 activities never alive at a time. If we navigate from one activity to another the source activity will go to on stop state. After that y you can only come back using start activity or popbackstack. If you are using popback stack you can use setResult() instead of start activity.

Comment: Right, but what i want to achieve is that my current activity doesn't go away, but does send my data to my other activity but still shows my first activity.

Comment: Can you show me the code snippet that you use to show 2 activities at a time.?

Comment: No i don't show 2 activities at once, i was wrong but i go from my MainActivity to my second activity and i want to send data from my second activity to my MainActivity without showing my MainActivity